# How to add double/top formation to existing zigzag function

Tags: pine-script, zigzag

Below zigzag function is working. I would like to add double/top formation to this zigzag function. How to do this? I have spend three evenings googling a solution and tried hard with chatGPT, but no luck so far.

```
//@version=4
study("ZigZag1color", overlay=true, max_bars_back=500, max_lines_count=300)
prd = input(defval=3, title="ZigZag Period", minval=2, maxval=50)
showzigzag = input(defval=true, title="Show Zig Zag")
zigzag_color = input(defval=color.black, title="Zigzag Color")

float ph = highestbars(high, prd) == 0 ? high : na
float pl = lowestbars(low, prd) == 0 ? low : na
var dir = 0
dir := iff(ph and na(pl), 1, iff(pl and na(ph), -1, dir))
var max_array_size = 10
var zigzag = array.new_float(0)

add_to_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    array.unshift(zigzag, bindex)
    array.unshift(zigzag, value)
    if array.size(zigzag) > max_array_size
        array.pop(zigzag)
        array.pop(zigzag)

update_zigzag(value, bindex) =>
    if array.size(zigzag) == 0
        add_to_zigzag(value, bindex)
    else
        if (dir == 1 and value > array.get(zigzag, 0)) or (dir == -1 and value < array.get(zigzag, 0))
            array.set(zigzag, 0, value)
            array.set(zigzag, 1, bindex)
        0.

Round_it(value) => round(value / syminfo.mintick) * syminfo.mintick

dirchanged = change(dir)
if ph or pl
    if dirchanged
        add_to_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)
    else
        update_zigzag(dir == 1 ? ph : pl, bar_index)

if showzigzag and array.size(zigzag) >= 4
    var line zzline = na
    float val = array.get(zigzag, 0)
    int point = round(array.get(zigzag, 1))
    if change(val) or change(point)
        float val1 = array.get(zigzag, 2)
        int point1 = round(array.get(zigzag, 3))
        if change(val1) == 0 and change(point1) == 0
            line.delete(zzline)
        zzline := line.new(x1=point, y1=val, x2=point1, y2=val1, color=zigzag_color, width=2)
```

Comment: How do you want to define your double top ?